# Replacing beginning and end of multiple URLs in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, https

I'm in the process of converting my wordpress website to https, and the issue I have is that a bunch of pages have external embeds that require a different url for https.

So I need to replace:
http://online.anyflip.com/code1/code2/
with:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/code1/code2/index.html

where code1 and code2 are different for each url.

So something like:

```
UPDATE wpe_posts 
SET    post_content = ( Replace (post_content, 'src="http://online.anyflip.com/$code1$/$code2$/', 'src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/online.anyflip.com/$code1$/$code2$/index.html') )
```

That isn't this obviously wrong.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're lucky if the prefix to each string is the same length because then you can use `SUBSTR()` to extract the `code1/code2` part.

Comment: I ended up chaning every entry manually, but thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

Instead of replacing Entire String just replace the part after src,

```
SET    post_content = ( Replace (post_content, 'http://online.anyflip.com/$code1$/$code2$/', 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/online.anyflip.com/$code1$/$code2$/index.html') )
```

Comment: Kindly provide the Tick if you got the expected result.

Comment: Thank you trying to help, but I think you might have missed the point: post_content are whole html pages and I want to replace some URLs within the code while keeping what's in $code1 and $code2, which change for every entry. Having src or not in there isn't the issue.